# League of Legends: My game is freezing out of nowhere

Tags: league-of-legends, technical-issues

I am playing League of Legends with around 33 ping and great wifi, but about 6-10 times a game out of nowhere my game just freezes for about 5 seconds. I would think that this is an issue with my wifi but my wifi is always up and it happens every game.
I have seen stuff about lag spikes but this is not a lag spike because my ping stays the same, is this a known glitch? Because I can't find it anywhere, if so or if not is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Is the game installed on a hard drive or SSD? If it's the former then it could be that it is struggling to read the game files at times and thus causing the spikes. Also have you checked that your graphics drivers are up to date?

Comment: @Oast it's a game you download from online :)

Comment: I've played quite a lot of League in the past, I understand it's online but you still have to download it to your PC :-) you should definitely check your drivers are up to date as a first thing to try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you installed LoL a while ago?

There are often problems with logs starting to be too big and being 'too big to managed' by the OS.

https://support-leagueoflegends.riotgames.com/hc/en-us/articles/201752674-Network-System-and-League-of-Legends-Logs#section-windows

Basically, in windows, opening a 4k file on the fly? no sweat. Opening a 4gb file on the fly? that could cause problems.

So my guess is you might have huge log files, and when it needs to open it to write something in it, you experience the freeze.

Comment: is there a way to fix it?

Comment: If you find your logs, you can delete them with no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Basically what @Fredy31 said.
Addding to that you can download HexTech Repair Tool to delete log files IIRC.